# Fastest way to setup Hadoop cluster using Cloudera

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

Need some help here guys. I am new to Hadoop and I need to setup a Hadoop cluster fast using windows machines. 
I am aware that I can use Cloudera for this but I was just wondering that instead of downloading a virtual box first, configuring it with Ubuntu and then installing CDH4 on it, can I not just download a pre-configured VM that Cloudera provides on the different machines and then network them?

Is there any step by step tutorial available to do this using the VMs provided by Cloudera?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks,
Kumar

EDIT : I have VMPlayer, isos of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, CentOS 6.2, VirtualBox and fast internet. Now can someone tell me what's the fastest way of setting up a cluster using CDH4 on 4-5 laptops I have in a LAN with windows on them?

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to setup Cloudera Hadoop cluster is to install Cloudera Manager and leave all jobs to it.

First, install Cloudera manager server in one node, start the server service.

Second, install Cloudera manager agent on other nodes, set the hostname of server to /etc/cloudera-scm-agent/config.ini, then start all the agents.

Third, use a browser to visit the `http://cloudera-scm-server:7180`, then follow the wizard and Cloudera Manager will take care of all left jobs.